# What is more resource intensive, fopen+fwrite OR mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I'm writing a rather large script that will have to process a lot of data, however there are parts of it for logging, and I was wondering, what uses less resource, adding a file onto a line in a txt file or a mysql query? How would I go about testing this?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/How-to-Benchmark-PHP-Scripts-for-Speed/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$start = microtime(); 

// your process here

$end = microtime();

// Compare duration.
```